# LP converted dryer not heating - could low supply pressure be why?

Tags: dryer, propane

I have had a stack washer dryer for 15 years. It stopped heating last week.

1. I replaced the easy/cheap/likely first: thermistor, flame sensor,
   ignition coils
2. Then I replaced the more expensive but already
   malfunctioning control module.
3. I don't see a thermal fuse - if there
   is one it is not mounted on the heater housing. I don't see a
   thermal fuse listed as a part for my model FGQ1442ES0 Frigidaire
   either.
4. I Plugged in a new igniter.

After all that I am wondering if it is possible the propane supply tank isn't providing enough pressure- (its under 10% full and it has been relatively cold lately). Other LP appliances are working (tankless hot water). Probably wishful thinking - will be getting a delivery this week so... has anyone seen or heard of this on a propane conversion dryer?

Otherwise, the next things to replace are cycling thermostat and dryer moisture sensor.

I don't want to replace the full stack while prices are so inflated right now.

Comment: Is it trying to start?  A spark igniter will make clicking sounds, a glow plug igniter will glow red.  That should help narrow down the problem.  (BTW:  Did someone turn off the gas?).

Comment: It is not trying to start heating - no glow. Gas valve is in the on position, yes.

Comment: Dryers vibrate a lot.  It is possible an electrical connection became dislodged or broken.  I would check every connection carefully.

Comment: So far all connections have been solid. The last device in the chain is the cycling thermostat. It is located behind the mounting bracket for the drum bearing, and it is relatively expensive. Based on my rules of engagement I guess I am going to go after it next.

Comment: Update: I finally replaced the stack with a new Samsung set. I was surprised at what a difference the new units made in terms of quality. I don't do the laundry but I am hearing a lot of appreciation from the wife.